# Is there a way to get count of messages consumed by rabbitmq per schedule in python

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I schedule publisher every 3hrs and consumer runs indefinitely, is there a way to find out total number of messages consumed when the queue is empty after every schedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ doesn't trace this kind of information.
there are different ways to do that:

- Add a counters consumer side
- Use a monitoring system, see https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html